# PHPStorm 10 randomly ignores AltGr +8/9 to open brackets

Tags: phpstorm

I have a weird situation with the new version of PHPStorm 10.0.2.
I have a german keyboard and to open square brackets [] i need to type a combination of AltGr + 8 or 9 keys.

All works ok until, at some point in time, randomly, this combinations are ignored and they are being interpreted as Alt+Strg (Alt+Ctrl on englisch keyboard) + 8 or 9 which jumps from curly brackets up and down.

- This issue happens in Windows. Will update this question when I get to a linux machine, in case i can reproduce it.
- german keyboard layout is the default one on the machine so no other languages.

Anyone has this issue and how can this be solved?

**UPDATE 1:**
If i press Alt + AltGr and 8 or 9 it works correctly...

**UPDATE 2:**
I tried in Linux ctrl+alt does not have the same effect like on windows. So it is a windows only issue

Comment: Do you have only the German keyboard layout? If you also have another one that doesn't use `AltGr` to produce some symbols (the English keyboards f.e.), a cause for this behaviour could be the English keyboard layout being active when you press the `AltGr` combination of keys.

Comment: What OS do you use? The behaviour of the special keys is dependent on the OS and also PhpStorm uses different keyboard shortcuts on Windows, Linux and OSX.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was driving me insane!!!

However, it was not random (though I initially thought it was).

**Steps to reproduce (German keyboard):**

1. Open IDE
2. Open first project (AltGr + 8 or 9 will work as expected)
3. Open second project in a new window (AltGr + 8 or 9 will now start to switch projects and no longer work until only one window remains)

**Steps to fix:**

1. Open `<SYSTEM DRIVE>\Users\<USER ACCOUNT NAME>\.<PRODUCT><VERSION>\config\options\keyboard.xml` (e.g. `C:\Users\John\.WebIde100\config\options\keyboard.xml`)
2. Set "USE_NON_ENGLISH_KEYBOARD" to false

Comment: doesn't work with phpstorm 2017 (and webstorm 2017). there is no `keyboard.xml` file in the config/options folder.

Answer (score 4):

Did you enable "German layout support" option? See [IDEA-142462](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-142462) - may be related. Enabling `actionSystem.force.alt.gr=true` (https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-91975#comment=27-384169) may help...